# Why is this proof incorrect? (Follow up question to: if $A$ is nilpotent, $B = c_0I + c_1A + \dots + c_{m-1}A^{m-1}$, $\det(B) = 0$ iff $c_0=0$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This is a follow up question to this question: [Suppose $A$ is nilpotent, and $B = c_0I_n + c_1A + \cdots + c_{m-1}A^{m-1}$, show $\det(B) = 0$ iff $c_0 = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441762/suppose-a-is-nilpotent-and-b-c-0i-n-c-1a-cdots-c-m-1am-1-sho) , which I asked months ago. I've copied and pasted the original statement below:

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, with real entries. If $A$ is nilpotent, so $A^m = 0$ for some $m \ge 1$, $B = c_0I_n + c_1A + \cdots + c_{m-1}A^{m-1}$, where $c_i \in R$ for each $i$, show that $\det(B) = 0$ if and only if $c_0 = 0$.

I was reviewing this question (I'm doing problems in preparation for a qual), and although the answers in the original question make sense to me, as I was redoing the problem I proved that if $\det(B) = 0$, then $c_0$ cannot be equal to $0$. Obviously this is false, but I can't figure out where in my proof I made the mistake. Here it is:

If $\det(B) = 0$, $B$ is invertible, and cannot have $0$ as an eigenvalue. Using the form of $B$ given in the problem statement, we can write

$$B - c_0I = c_1A + \dots c_{m-1}A^{m-1},$$

which means that $Av \in N(B - c_0I)$ for any $v \in V$, which means that $Av$ is an eigenvector of $B$ corresponding to eigenvalue $c_0$, for any $v \in V$. But this means that $c_0$ cannot be equal to $0$.

Obviously, if $Av = 0$ for all $v \in V$, there is a problem, but then we just have

$$B = c_0I,$$

(since $A$ is just the $0$ matrix), and this clearly implies that $c_0 = 0$ if $\det(B) = 0$.

What am I missing, here? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you mean "If $\det(B)\not=0$" about halfway down the question?   I'm having trouble parsing what you wrote because there are places where $\not=0$'s are missing (or imply the opposite conclusion).  Could you check your statements?

Comment: There are two mistakes in your proof. The first mistake was pointed out by Michael Burr. The second is that you write that each $Av$ is in the kernel of $B - c_0I$. Why should this be true? However, *one* vector $v$ from the kernel of $A$ should be enough. Then it is also in the kernel of $B - c_0I$, so $c_0\neq 0$.

Comment: Oh wow, yep, if $\det(B) = 0$, then $B$ is not invertible... I completely mixed myself up. Thanks. It's been a long day!

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp thank you for pointing those out! What I was thinking, but did not write correctly, was that for each $v \in V$, $A^{m-1}v \in \ker(B-c_0I)$, since then $B-c_0I = c_1A^mv + c_2A^{m+1} + \dots + c_{m-1}A^{2m-2} = 0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction is easy.  If $c_0=0$, then $B$ is also nilpotent, so its determinant is zero.

If $c_0\not=0$, then $B-c_0I$ is nilpotent.  If $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$, then it must be an eigenvector of $B-c_0I$.  Since $B-c_0I$ is nilpotent, you can conclude that the eigenvalue for $v$ is $c_0$, and not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: All the eigenvalues of A are zeros (iterate the equation relating A, an eigenvalue and the associated eigenvector). It follows that all the eigenvectors of A are eigenvectors of B corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = c_{0}$. Thus $\det B = c_{0}^{n}$ and the result desired drops out immediately.

Comment: The eigenvectors don't span the space in general. $A$ could have only one eigenvector (up to lin. dependence).

Comment: You have a point.

Comment: But you are actually right. We have $(B - c_0I)^m = 0$. Thus, $c_0$ is the only eigenvalue of $B$ and $p_B(t) = (t - c_0)^n$. Hence $\det(B - tI) = (c_0-t)^n$, resulting in $\det B = c_0^n$.